# Is there a list of public "POST test" webpages like this one?

Tags: https, http, testing, test

For various automated tests that I do, I need to be able to make a `POST` HTTP & HTTPS request to some external URL and essentially have that webpage "echo" what I sent. For example, if I send the POST variable "meow" with the value "bark", I want both "meow" and "bark" to be presented somehow on the webpage.

I have found many ones which do this for GET data, but only one single service which does it for POST data. Namely this one: https://httpbin.org/post

While it currently works, and has worked for years, I always feel scared to depend on a single source for anything. That's why I'm looking for (preferably) many more ones which I can rotate between, which also would put less strain on that one service. (Although my testing isn't at all as heavy as this may seem to imply.)

Just before asking this question, I spent a long time wading through search results, finding numerous very weird websites which seemed like they would be related to this, but ended up being nonsense, as so often is the case. Please don't post links to search engine-found results unless you have actually tried that they work, because many of them just output a generic message and don't actually echo the POST data, so you can't be sure that they are really reporting the truth.

(If I see my randomized code in the return data, I know it worked, but if it just says "it worked!" I have to take their word for it.)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you run your own?

For [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org), the source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/httpbin) and it's also available on [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/kennethreitz/httpbin/):

> Run locally:
>
> ```
> docker pull kennethreitz/httpbin
> docker run -p 80:80 kennethreitz/httpbin
> ```
>
> See http://httpbin.org for more information.

Also, you could achieve what you ask for i.e. "presented somehow" e.g. with a PHP one-liner:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: The question was about external URLs -- not how to code and host it myself. It's the simplest thing in the world from a technical perspective, and obviously, I would do it myself if that were an option, instead of asking for external resources.

Comment: And yet, *product, service, or learning material recommendations* are [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on ServerFault, so this is the only answer that's within the scope of this site. The reason is that even if we would publish such a list, it would become obsolete very quickly.